# How can I make this Javascript code unobtrusive?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, unobtrusive-javascript

```
<div id="detailed">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Result.Items)
    {                
        <div id="movie_@(movie.UserMovieID)" class="movie border-gray">
            <!-- Some html code -->
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            new InitMovieWicket(@(MvcHtmlString.Create(movie.ToJSon())),"movie_@(movie.UserMovieID)");    
        </script>
    }
</div>
```

I am getting list of movie objects from ASP.NET MVC server-side and generating html like above. As you can see , I am also initializing javascript wickets for each of these movies by using movies's JSON data and script tags.

I want to remove these script tags from html and javascript code to be unobtrusive but I dont know how to do that because for each movie to create wicket I need JSON data and without rendering time script tags I cannot see a way to do this. Do you have any idea ? Thanks..

**Update** 
I want want my html code to look like this.

```
<div id="detailed">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Result.Items)
    {                
        <div id="movie_@(movie.UserMovieID)" class="movie border-gray">
            <!-- Some html code -->
        </div>            
    }
</div>
```

And I want my Javascript code to look like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {                
    //init all movie wickets               
 });
```

Comment: what is the responsibility of your javascript code? What should the unobtrusive version look like (with javascript disabled, for example)?

Comment: @Groo : I have updated. You can see how my code can look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how I'd do it:

1. Put only one script tag in the `<head></head>` part where you initialize an JSON array with all the movies in it (on the server side) like:

   var movies = '[{"userMovieID": "123", ...}, {"userMovieID": "432", ...}]';
2. when the document is ready, you should start building the widgets by first parsing the json array and then iterating through the array of movies, then create a Widget for every movie and insert

   ```
   <div id="movie_@(movie.UserMovieID)" class="movie border-gray">
       <!-- Some html code -->
   </div>
   ```

to your `<div id="detailed">..</div>`, maybe you want to use Javascript Templates like [jquery-tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)

The best solution would be if your widget class "InitMovieWicket" creates the `<div id="movie_"..>...</div>` entry.

Comment: Wouldnt be violation of graceful degradation if I would create wicket html code in Javascript ?What about if users turn off javascript ?

Comment: you're right, if it should work with javascript turned off then insert the divs as you do now but still create the json array and iterate through it. Because you can easily lookup the associated movie <div> tag by the ID of the movie. This might be better because you start initialize the widgets when the DOM Document is ready, this means you can be sure the movie <div> tag exists when you initialize the movie widget classes.

Answer (score 2):

A potentially better way, for users which don't have JavaScript enabled but still want to see movie details for each item, would be to actually render those details as HTML elements, and then hide them if JavaScript is available.

For example, you would render your HTML to look something like:

```
<div id="detailed">
    <div id="movie_@1234" class="movie border-gray">
        <div class="wicketData title">Some title</div>
        <div class="wicketData year">Year</div>
        <div class="wicketData synopsis">Some other stuff</div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

And then iterate through the elements and replace divs with anything you like:

```
$(doument).ready(function() {                

    // get the parent div
    var $detailedParent = $("#detailed");

    // get a list of all movie class divs
    var $items = $detailedParent.find(".movie");

    $.each($items, function(i) {

        // get the movie div
        var movie = $items[i];

        // get all wicket data
        var data = movie.find(".wicketData");

        // prepare the JSON data using DOM
        var movieData = {
             title = data.children("title").text(),
             year = data.children("year").text(),
             synopsis = data.children("synopsis").text()
        };

        // remove or hide dummy elements
        data.remove();

        // init your wicket
        new InitMovieWicket(movieData, movie.attr('id'));
    };

});
```

This will allow users without JavaScript to get a bit degraded presentation, but all the data will still be there.

Comment: I liked your idea too but when there are lots of data in movie, this can lead html to grow quickly and Don't you think it can be needless to get a lot of html and consume bandwithd for a high traffic web site ?

Comment: @mcaaltuntas: But isn't this the same data you are passing in JSON objects right now?

Comment: yes It is but in html version there are lots of extra html tags like div,class etc am I right ?

Comment: @mcaaltuntas: That's correct, JSON is very compact compared to HTML. If actual content is usually small in size, it might make a large difference (again, depending on the number of movies you wish to display on one page). In the end it will all depend on how much you really want to show to this portion of your users; maybe you need to show a few tags, maybe none. But this is what progressive enhancement is about.